# getting error when run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

New to ruby on rails , I'm getting this below error its trying to read some JSON file and getting the error in JSON.   Any help would be much appreciated.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
(in /srv/dev/rails_app.rails)
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Oj::ParseError: quoted string not terminated at line 1, column 385025 [load.c:994]
/home/dev/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.10.1/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:16:in `parse'
```

......
.....

Here is the full trace  http://pastebin.com/pmKEpbWM

Comment: @vijdhama ..  sorry I do not know where exactly its picking the JSON file.

Comment: It's difficult to help you without code or the JSON. I'd recommend using a JSON validator to confirm the input file's syntax. Once you know where the unterminated string starts you can then fix the file, or the program that generates the file.

Comment: you should inspect that json file. Sounds like its not bracketed closed(?)

Comment: thanks all. I got it finally I found the JSON file and there was some weird character and was detectable by VI. Its working now.